# Using localhost in a NiFi Remote Processor Group URL

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a clustered NiFi setup (2-nodes) and have gotten Remote Process Groups to work when I explicitly list the IP address of one of the nodes in the RPG URL (http://:8080/nifi). The problem is with the use of RPG's in templates, I need to recreate these RPG's with the new node information for that cluster environment (Test->Stage->Prod). Is it possible to somehow use localhost as the address for this URL so that templates that include RPG's remain portable throughout environments?

Answer (score 4):

I know this does not address your immediate question, but there is a JIRA that has been completed and tagged for the next release of NiFi which makes the RPG URL editable:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4526

This would make it so that the value in your template doesn't really matter because you can change it after import.

Comment: Thank you. It's good to know that the field will be editable in a future release.